# Sass Susy gallery: element that spans two columns

Tags: html, css, grid, sass, susy

[image: Imgur]
I need to make some elements of susy's gallery mixin span two columns, the problem is as shown in the picture it does not push the other elements after it, even though I tried to do that manually. How could this be done.
The link to the code https://github.com/iyedg/IGBlogTheme

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you already tried? It's kind of hard to help you based on just an image

Comment: I've got a similar issue. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://zellwk.com/blog/susy-gallery-problems/) is the perfect tutorial about gallery with different size items.

And the main point is: You can't achieve this with `gallery()` mixin, but it's possible with `span()` mixin by something like

```css
$susy: (
  columns: 12, 
  output: isolate
);

// Assuming output is set to isolate
.gallery__item {
  margin-bottom: gutter();
  @include span(4 of 12 split); 

  &:nth-child(4),
  &:nth-child(7), {
    width: span(8 of 12 split);
  }
}
```