# In a Susy gallery I need to span the first element across the first two gallery columns

Tags: sass, susy

[Another very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958490/sass-susy-gallery-element-that-spans-two-columns?rq=1) has already been asked.

I've set a gallery composed of elements in six columns. However I want the first element to span the first two columns of the gallery.

[image: Screen shot of my current, wrong, layout]

```
$deskcol : 12;

.colSixth {
  @include gallery(2 of $deskcol);
}

.colSixth.strap {
  ??
}

<div class="colSixth strap">
   content should span two Sixths
</div>
<article class="colSixth">
    content spans one sixth
</article>
<article class="colSixth">
    content spans one sixth
</article>
<article class="colSixth">
    content spans one sixth
</article>
<article class="colSixth">
    content spans one sixth
</article>
```

Is there a way to offset the `gallery` function by two? I've tried isolating it. And I've added extra padding on the `.strap` element, but it pushes the first row of gallery out and off the page. And even tried `&:first-child` selectors in various flavours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never really solved this with a Susy gallery offset rule of sorts. Instead I resorted to wrapping each pair of `<article>`elements in a `.colThird` and nesting the two `.colSixth` elements inside them.

```
.colThird {
   @include gallery(4 of $deskcol);
}

.colSixth {
   @include span(2 of 4);
   &:last-child {
    @include omega;
   }
}

<div class="colThird">
   <div class="colSixth strap">
      content should span two Sixths
   </div>
</div>

<div class="colThird">
   <article class="colSixth">
       content spans one sixth
   </article>
   <article class="colSixth">
       content spans one sixth
   </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you only want the first item to span two columns? In that case, you might not want to use the gallery function (use span instead).

To make things simple, you might also want to switch gutters to inside.

Here's what you can do instead:

```
.colSixth {
  @iinclude span(2 of 12 inside); 

  &:first-child {
    @include span(4 of 12 inside); 
  }
}
```

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I'll bear it in mind for the next time. But my initial gut feeling is that I'd prefer to use the gallery function because it would facilitate creating different column layouts at different breakpoints.

Comment: @Seb using span would help you even more with creating different column layouts at different breakpoints (in this code). You just have to change the width and context.

Comment: In contrast, your's will take more code to produce the same effect at different breakpoints. Give it a try.